# How to convert .qm and .ts files to .mo or .po?

Tags: qt, translation, gettext

I'm working with several language files and sometimes the sources are in .qm/.ts format. I'm using Qt Linguist/Gtranslator/POEdit but AFAIK none of these can convert these files to .mo/.po. Are there any program capable for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use lconvert

```
lconvert <file>.ts -o <file>.po
```

Comment: Oh cool. One last thing before I accept. Are there any GUI solution too?

Comment: Could be, but I am unfamiliar.